# Why is my program not opening my .dat file?

Tags: java, io, binary

Hi my java program is supposed to read in and display a .txt file the user enters when prompted, convert the integers in the file to an output .dat file, then read in that .dat file and display the numbers again.  When I run my program it displays the contents of the file, and creates the .dat file, but dosn't read it in again.  My code is below.  What do I need to do?

```
public class InputFile
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

            System.out.print("Enter file name (with .txt extension): ");
            Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inFileName = keys.next();

            try
            {
                inputStream = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(inFileName));
                System.out.println("The file " + inFileName + " contains the following lines:");
                String inFileString = inputStream.readLine();
                while(inFileString != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(inFileString);
                    inFileString = inputStream.readLine();
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println(inFileName + " not found! Try Again.");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            String fileName = "numbers.dat";
            try
            {
                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                int anInt = 0;
                while(anInt >=0);
                {
                    anInt = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.readLine());
                    outputStream.writeInt(anInt);
                }
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem opening file.");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem with output to the file.");
            }

            try
            {
                ObjectInputStream inputStream2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                System.out.println("The file being read yields:");
                int anInteger = inputStream2.readInt();
                while(anInteger >= 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(anInteger);
                        anInteger = inputStream2.readInt();
                    }
                inputStream2.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem with opening the file.");
            }
            catch(EOFException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem reading the file.");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("There was a problem reading the file.");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably combine the first two `while` loops.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm newer to java.  It compiles and runs without any error messages. and @irrelephant, how would you suggest i do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistype (or at least I suppose it was a mistype) hard to spot that makes your second loop infinite.

```
 (...)
 try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            int anInt = 0;
            while(anInt >=0);  <=====
            {
                anInt = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.readLine());
                outputStream.writeInt(anInt);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        }
```

Remove this ';' after the while and I guess it'll run normally.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't even see that!  I removed it and it does run, but now I get "Problem with output to the file.
The file being read yields:
Problem reading the file." displayed on the screen :(

Comment: You're closing the input stream just after reading it, so when you try to read it again it's closed. Try to reopen it before creating the outputStream (ie: inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFileName)); ObjectOutputStream outputStream (...))

Comment: hmmm :/ that just yields this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
 at InputFile.main(InputFile.java:63)"

Comment: Well, you probably have a line that's not a number on your input file. You could wrap your "Integer.parseInt(..)" with a try { } catch (NumberFormatException e) { anInt = -1; }. This way you will stop copying the read numbers to your output stream if you find a line that's not a number in your input.

Comment: @Derek could you include the content of your `.txt` file?

Comment: Sorry guys it probably would be helpful to see my text file huh? haha here it is
"4
7
23
19"
and each number is on a new line

Comment: I guess your problem could be a blank space before the new line.
Try to do this: anInt = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.readLine().trim());

Comment: adding the .trim() yielded "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at InputFile.main(InputFile.java:63)"

Comment: Then I guess you should do some "checking" on the information you just read from the inputstream. Maybe you should assign it to a string, verify if it's not null, call trim(..) and then try to parse it as an integer, but wrapping this parsing with a try { ... } catch (NumberFormatException e) { ... }.

Comment: @Derek Your `readLine()`s are null, and it's the `while(anInt >=0)` logic that's causing this. Just because the current number is non-negative doesn't mean the next number will exist. Should be something like `String s = ""; while((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) { anInt = Integer.parseInt(s); `

Comment: Well, Derek's .txt doesn't have a number that's (< 0), so "inputStream.readLine()" will return null sometime. Derek, what I guess you should do, besides all checking we mentioned above, is fixing your logic so that you don't get caught in an inifite loop (ie: breaking the loop when you find the end of the inputStream - if ((line = inputStream.readLine()) == null) { break; }).

Comment: still not working guys :/ no errors, just dosnt have any additional screen output besides the numbers

Answer (score 1):

you are not writing to the output stream because by that time the inputStream has been exhausted and is closed.

create a collection to store the elements from the first file.

```
String inFileName = keys.next();
Collection<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
...
System.out.println(inFileString);
lines.add(inFileString);

...
for(String line : lines){
...
    outputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(line));
...
}
```